# Log setState calls

Tags: reactjs

In redux, you can console log the action that is received in the reducer to debug state issues, is there a similar way to do it with the setState api?

I have a rather large abstracted code base and trying to debug a certain issue, not as simple to just look for a setState call on the property

Comment: as an update, I do see the diff in prevState and nextState, and know how my state is changing, I am looking for a way to see the function call that is changing it

Comment: Did you find a way to do so?

Comment: no, there is no way to retroactively get this to my knowledge. The only way to really do it is creating a helper function that does the `setState` call and logs as well.

Comment: In the meantime I have found this tool that served me well for my purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-log-state

Answer (score 4):

From [`React`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) docs:

1. `setState` take a callback as a second parameter

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered

So it might be helpful for you to perform some debug in a callback function.

2. Another way is to use `comonentDidUpdate`

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render
>
> `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`

Depends on your logic you can do same thing here:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if(this.state.foo !== prevState.foo){
    console.log('FOO')
  } 
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, useful info! I was thinking for a way to do it globally in the instance I was unsure of where the erroneous setState call was coming from

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your component is extending React Component, you can add this method in your component class to log setState method:

```
setState(newState) {
    const { state } = this;
    console.log('prevState ');
    console.log(state);

    console.log('newState ');
    console.log(newState);

    super.setState(newState);
  }
```